# Reactive Framework (RX) and dealing with events Asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

So I'm just playing around with RX and learning it. I started playing with Events, and wanted to know how to subscribe to events, and process the results in batches asynchronously. Allow me to explain with code:

Simple class that raises events:

```
public class EventRaisingClass
{
   public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> EventOccured;

   //some other code that raises event...
}

public class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SomeEventArgs(int data)
    {
        this.SomeArg = data;
    }

    public int SomeArg { get; private set; }
}
```

Then my Main:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var eventRaiser = new EventRaisingClass();
    IObservable<IEvent<SomeEventArgs>> observable = 
        Observable.FromEvent<SomeEventArgs>(e => eventRaiser.EventOccured += e, e => eventRaiser.EventOccured -= e);

    IObservable<IList<IEvent<SomeEventArgs>>> bufferedEvents = observable.BufferWithCount(100);

    //how can I subscribte to bufferedEvents so that the subscription code gets called Async?
    bufferedEvents.Subscribe(list => /*do something with list of event args*/); //this happens synchrounously...

}
```

As you can see in my comments, when you just call subscribe like that, all the subscription code happens synchronously. Is there a way out of the box using RX to have the Subscribe be called on different threads whenever there's a new batch of events to work on?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for `SubscribeOn` or `ObserveOn`, passing an `IScheduler`. There are several schedulers built-in under `System.Concurrency`; some of them use whatever thread is current, and others use specific threads.

[This video](https://web.archive.org/web/20100820055513/http://channel9.msdn.com:80/posts/J.Van.Gogh/Controlling-concurrency-in-Rx/) has more info on the scheduler concept.

The Rx team also recently released a [hands-on labs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rxteam/rx-hands-on-labs-published) document which is the closest thing to a tutorial right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
bufferedEvents.ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool).Subscribe(...
```

SubscribeOn is to specify the schedule on which so-called "*subscription side effects*" are happening. For example, your observable can open a file each time somebody subscribes.

ObserveOn is to specify the schedule on which the call to the observer will happen every time when there is a new value. In practice, it is used more often than SubscribeOn.