# RX Scheduler - What is it?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm reading up on RX and totally bamboozled to what the Scheduler is intended for? 
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `IScheduler` interface in Rx helps an IObservable "schedule" it's subscription appropriately.  This is very important in order to handle thread affinity and similar issues, since the subscription will be causing something to happen at some point.

Here is a [good description of the IScheduler interface](http://bvanderveen.com/a/async-with-rx-and-the-tpl-part-3) (along with a comparison to the TPL's TaskScheduler).

Comment: Thanks Reed, that link was very handy

Answer (score 2):

This class is for basically what it implies.  It is a mechanism for scheduling the internal threads that make up the Rx framework.  There is a great video on this [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/j.van.gogh/controlling-concurrency-in-rx).

The [main page](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/) for Rx contains more videos that offer insight into the architecture as well as use of the framework.

Comment: that answer looks just like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215019/reactive-framework-rx-and-dealing-with-events-asynchronously

Comment: Which answer? Looks different to me.