# What's the best way to invoke Observable method at a specific time?

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am using RX to create an Asynchronous Web request. Is there a good scheduler to invoke a Web Request at a predefined time? I am confused which one to use: Task Scheduler or RX Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Rx I'd stick with Rx.

Try using this to schedule your web request:

```
Scheduler.ThreadPool
    .Schedule(
        DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1.0),
        () => { /* Do web request */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Rx Scheduler and Task scheduler are different things. Rx Scheduler is used to helps an IObservable "schedule" it's subscription appropriately (refer this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046344/rx-scheduler-what-is-it)). Where as Task scheduler are how a Task (which is a abstract concept) will be executed i.e on same thread OR in thread pool etc. You want to generate a Async Web request at a specified time, for that you can use any of the [Timer objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) from BCL.